# Adding permissions to github repository only

Tags: github

I have an organization and want to add granular permissions for each repo. This does not seem possible and the docs send me to "Setting the base level permissions" which I do not want.

[github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-access-to-your-organizations-repositories/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is adding a person in the `Settings` of each repo. Should be in the docs.

Also, this is a stupid and dangerous way of adding people in an organization as I could easily add someone to this repo from outside the organization if I'm not careful. Very, very stupid. I should only be able to add people from WITHIN my organization, that's the entire f... point of having one in the first place.

[image]